# Combined diagram with area chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, diagrams, data-visualization

*[moved from stackoverflow]*

I have an combined diagram like this one:

[image: Diagram]

Is there a way to bring the red area into the foreground?

I'm using Excel 2013, i.e. v15.0

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25928248/4497791), most likely not, but it mentions a couple of workarounds.

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)